# I want to write an expression String+date which could be evaluated using spEl

Tags: java, spring-el

I have an input for example: filename_+new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(new Date())

Output should be the filename_2019-07-04, how to achieve this?

What would be a proper way to handle it using Spring expression language?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern would probably be :- "filename_" + new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new java.util.Date())

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the easiest way, but you could achieve that using custom (own) methods in SpEL

https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-el-method-invocation-example/

Comment: I don't want to use custom methods, can't I use ExpressionParser to do the same in a single line

Comment: Somethings like this: 

ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("'fileName_'.concate('new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(new Date())'");
String message = (String) exp.getValue();